# How to handle two endpoints in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have written request two end points. Both are same only difference in second end point is added version like:

- 1st endpoint `{name}/{id}`
- 2nd endpoint `/v2/{name}/{id}`

It is working fine when i am calling with complete end point with complete path but when i am calling second endpoint by removing last path then it is calling 1st end point instead of calling 2nd endpoint

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "info")
public class Controller {

    @RequestMapping(value = "{college}/{name}/{id}",method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String get(@PathVariable(value = "college",required=true) String college,
              @PathVariable(value = "name", required = true) String name,
              @PathVariable(value = "id", required = true) String id) {
        return "THIS IS WORKING";
    }
    
    @RequestMapping(value = "/v2/{college}/{name}/{id}",method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String get1(@PathVariable(value = "college",required=true) String college,
              @PathVariable(value = "name", required = name) String name,
              @PathVariable(value = "id", required = true) String id) {
        return "THIS IS WORKING in V2";
    }

}
```

If i am calling second endpoint like by removing last value `/v2/111/222/` then it is hitting first endpoint.
I want to call second endpoint even if i remove the last variable. And i must use path variables. I cant change it to request parameters. It is my requirement

Comment: This is why you always add `/v1` in the first version.

Comment: If vin=v2 doesn't mean anything in the first endpoint then you can forward the request to second endpoint when vin.equals("v2"). This is not recommended but shall work when there is no other option

Answer (score 3):

This happens because `v2` string matches `vin` variable in first endpoint.
You can add a regular expression to prevent this behavior

#### Variant 1

Specify the minimum length for `vin` variable

`@GetMapping("{vin:.{10,}}/{can}/{val}")`

#### Variant 2

Variable `vin` must not be equal `v2`

`@GetMapping("{vin:^(?!(?:v2)\$).+\$}/{can}/{val}")`

Answer (score 0):

Version 1 API:
{vin}/{can}/{val}

Version 2 API:
/v2/{vin}/{can}/{val}

As you specified, you are calling API /v2/111/222/, this does not fulfill v2 API specification as the 3rd path variable(val) is not present. v1 is fulfilling the request as v2 maps to {vin}, 111 maps to {can} and 222 maps to {val}.

**Solution:**
Use v1/{vin}/{can}/{val} for version 1 API.

Comment: Thanks. Yes understood. Thing is I can't change the APIs definition now. Because  I have to change everything on UI side, wso2 configuration. It's just one example. In my project more than 100 APIs handles like that. Is there another solution to handle the APIs without changing the APIs signature